# REST API routes for blog-module

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I can't seem to find the API routes for this module, while the module is available by API.

How can I translate the code to API routes?

https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog

Answer (score 1):

They are not defined the  API points using `webapi.xml`.

So, you have to create API points yourself.

it is very good  they have defined API Data provider classes, APi interfaces.

If you want to   create api then class files located at  https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog/tree/master/Repository ,can be used  as API points

> But search API  data does not integrate with this module.